# Descarga de SQL Server edición Express y luego la edición Developer

Tags: sql-server

Si ya tengo instalado SQL Server en la edición Express y deseo instalar la edición Developer, ¿debo desinstalar la edición Express antes?
Gracias por su respuesta.

Comment: No tienes porque desinstalar lo anterior. Puedes tener tantas ediciones y versiones diferentes como quieras. Cada instalación (instancia), será algo independiente, aunque tendrán cosas comunes. Es más puedes tener varias instalaciones de la misma edición y de la misma versión en la misma máquina.

Comment: La respuesta a la pregunta es "no". Pero esa respuesta, y  por tanto la pregunta, no son adecuadas para el sitio, me temo que será cerrada.